# Writing a htaccess file - RewriteBase?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, dns, hosting, domain-mapping

Right I'll try and explain my situation as thoroughly as possible while also keeping it brief...

I'm just starting out as a web designer/developer, so I bought the unlimited hosting package with 123-reg. I set up a couple of websites, my main domain being designedbyross.co.uk. I have learnt how to map other domains to a folder within this directory. At the minute, one of my domains, scene63.com is mapped to designedbyross.co.uk/blog63 which is working fine for the home page. However when clicking on another link on scene63.com for example page 2, the URL changes to designedbyross.co.uk/blog63/page2...

I have been advised from someone at 123-reg that I need to write a .htaccess file and use the RewriteBase directive (whatever that is?!) I have looked on a few websites to try and help me understand this, including http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html however it all isn't making much sense at the moment.

Finally, scene63.com is a wordpress site, whether that makes any difference to how the htaccess file is structured I'm not sure...

Any help will be REALLY appreciated - Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a 123-reg problem at the time not correctly applying changes to the DNS.

Answer (score 0):

I run my personal public website on Webfusion, which is another branded service offering by the same company on the same infrastructure, and my blog contains a bunch of articles (tagged [Webfusion](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/search-Webfusion)) on how to do this.  You really need to do some reading and research -- the Apache docs, articles and HowTos like mine -- to help you get started and then come back with specific Qs, plus the supporting info that we need to answer them.

It sounds like you are using a 123 redirector service, or equivalent for scene63.com which hides the redirection in an iframe.  The issue here is that if the links on your site use site-relative links then because the URI has been redirected to `http://designedbyross.co.uk/blog6/...` then any new pages will be homed in `designedbyross.co.uk`.  (I had the same problem with my wife's business site which mapped the same way to one of my subdirectories).

What you need to do is to configure the blog so that its site base is `http://scene63.com/` and to force explicit site-based links so that any hrefs in the pages are of the form `http://scene63.com/page2`, etc.  How you do this depends on the blog engine, but most support this as an option.